# MariaDB volume in docker-compose clears out data

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm using the yobasystems/alpine-mariadb docker image to run an instance for a development environment. I'm mounting the data directory for MySQL to a docker volume and this has worked in the past. Every so often I lose data but not the table structure and I cannot work out why.

```
db:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "33333:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Note: there are an increasing number of ransomware attacks targeting MySQL/MariaDB container deployments that are directly exposed to the internet. This is a common symptom of those attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that in your case the volume is getting removed(may be via `docker-compose down -v` or `dockere-compose rm -v`).

Please specify that the volume is external using -

```
volumes:
  mariadb:
    external: true
```

From docker docs - *external: If set to true, specifies that this volume has been created outside of Compose. docker-compose up does not attempt to create it, and raises an error if it doesn’t exist.*

You may create the volume prior to `docker-compose up` with `docker volume create mariadb`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't understand why my table structure would be retained though? Surely if the volume is getting removed I would lose absolutely everything?

Comment: Are there any other services in this compose file? Maybe they depend on this db service and create tables while container starts.